# Android, change button style at runtime

Tags: android, button, styles, runtime

I need to change button style from "contained" to "outlined" at runtime.

[image] [image]

For now the only way I've found to create an outlined button is to set its style to `?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle`.
Unfortunately I haven't found a way to change the style at runtime, is it possible?

Is there any way to get this effect?

Comment: You can't do it. You can just create another Button. Is Compose an option?

Answer (score 0):

As a view with text inside, it should have "setTextAppearance" function. It's not the ideal option but may help. Also can be useful to look on https://github.com/airbnb/paris.